# Google Maps polyline drawing using only address

Tags: google-maps

I know that it does not exist ; but just to make to make sure , is it possible to draw polyline between two points using not coordinates , but with address only .

Thanks to those guys who will not down-vote my question .

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You can see this [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline). But you can get lat-lng of any address by using this [web service](http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=london&output=csv) from google and then you can draw polyline over it.

Answer (score 0):

its not posible directly, Reverse geo code address and than draw polyline